# Verify SSH Fingerprint about DNS SSHFP record fails

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, fingerprint

I have an Debian Jessie Server and I would like to verify the SSH HostKey about the [DNS SSHFP record](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121880/how-do-i-generate-sshfp-records). I only provide the ed25519 and rsa algorithm to connect to the server. I have masquerade the server FQDN to kronos.example.local.

I used this commands to generate the fingerprint for the ed25519 algorithm

```
root@kronos:~# ssh-keygen -r kronos.example.local -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
kronos.example.local IN SSHFP 4 1 f6291b4afb2b18cb3042e9dc01bd15efca7f5d5e
kronos.example.local IN SSHFP 4 2 7b2e9286d0969618ccb88d954587ac82f2ad471c34d07d25d91f9905b86f152d
```

and this one for rsa

```
root@kronos:~# ssh-keygen -r kronos.example.local -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
kronos.example.local IN SSHFP 1 1 365f966468f59ed889fb9d94c25f8f6cb858aa7a
kronos.example.local IN SSHFP 1 2 162f0117baae8380427698ba8800bdef36e150e6014f220b568d85445832d050
```

I used dig to check the records on my client machine.

```
volker@vm23 ~ $ dig SSHFP kronos.example.local
;; ANSWER SECTION:
kronos.example.local.   600 IN  SSHFP   1 2 162F0117BAAE8380427698BA8800BDEF36E150E6014F220B568D8544 5832D050
kronos.example.local.   600 IN  SSHFP   4 2 7B2E9286D0969618CCB88D954587AC82F2AD471C34D07D25D91F9905 B86F152D
kronos.example.local.   600 IN  SSHFP   4 1 F6291B4AFB2B18CB3042E9DC01BD15EFCA7F5D5E
kronos.example.local.   600 IN  SSHFP   1 1 365F966468F59ED889FB9D94C25F8F6CB858AA7A
```

The SSHFP Record is correct and I add the settings StrictHostKeyChecking and VerifyHostKeyDNS in my ssh config to verify the ssh fingerprint about the SSHFP record.

```
Host                    kronos
Hostname                kronos.example.local
Port                    30
User                    root
Compression             yes        
IdentityFile            ~/.ssh/ssh.key      
PasswordAuthentication  no
PubkeyAuthentication    yes
RSAAuthentication       no
StrictHostKeyChecking   yes
VerifyHostKeyDNS        yes
```

Now, when I want to connect to the Server I get an error, that my ssh-client can't establish an connection because the fingerprint is wrong?

```
volker@vm23 ~ $ ssh kronos
No ED25519 host key is known for [kronos.example.local]:30 and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

Why I get this error, I don't know what I make wrong.

**EDIT:**

When I flush the known_hosts file and connect again, I get this message with the provided fingerprint.

```
The authenticity of host '[kronos.example.local]:30 ([192.168.2.100]:30)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:ey6ShtCWlhjMuI2VRYesgvKtRxw00H0l2R+ZBbhvFS0.
```

Comment: Are the records already in the DNS? Can you verify that using `dig`?

Comment: Yes, the records are in the DNS. I used first my local DNS Server and second explicit the DNS from the example.local zone. (dig kronos.example.local SSHFP @ns1.example.local)

Comment: `StrictHostKeyChecking yes` prevents openssh from automatically adding new HostKeys to the `known_hosts` file. You will need to add it to `known_hosts` manually or set `StrictHostKeyChecking no` for your first connection. You will then be asked if you want to add it. Afterwards you can set it back to `StrictHostKeyChecking yes`.

Comment: Thanks Ismooth, it's works fine. At the first connection I get now this message `Matching host key fingerprint found in DNS.` when I have `StrictHostKeyChecking no`. When I change it to `yes` I can connect with verifying the fingerprint. Thanks!

Comment: @lsmooth Please provide that in answer format so that the Q&A can be closed and credit properly attributed. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewB sorry missed this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StrictHostKeyChecking yes` prevents openssh from automatically adding new HostKeys to the `known_hosts` file. You will need to add it to `known_hosts` manually or set `StrictHostKeyChecking no` for your first connection. You will then be asked if you want to add it. Afterwards you can set it back to `StrictHostKeyChecking yes`.